# React Select Option value when no change

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

**How to get the select value if there is no change?**

```
<select onChange={handleChange}>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

**Scenario:-**

If the user selects **B** I want to send that value to `handleChange` function.

If the user does not select an option then I want **A** to be sent to `handleChange` function.

How to achieve this in react?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultValue` for your purpose

```
<select defaultValue="A" onChange={handleChange}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `selected` argument to option `A` as follows.

```
<select onChange={handleChange}>
    <option value="A" selected>A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>

</select>
```

how to use `selected` when options are mapped using the map function?

You can use `selected` when options are mapped using `map` function.

```
<select
                  className="w-44 px-4 py-2 mt-2 border rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-600"
                  value={business_type}
                  onChange={(e) => setBusinessType(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <option value="1" selected="selected">
                    Business Type
                  </option>
                  {data?.businessTypeList?.map((x, y) => (
                    <option>{x.businessType}</option>
                  ))}
                </select>
```

You can replace `Business Type` with your own placeholder and map your array object with a single `option` so that your array instances will get displayed accordingly.

Happy coding.

Comment: how to use selected when options are mapped using the map function?

Comment: @TejasP You can refer my answer again I just edited as per your request. Do not forget to accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: yes this should work but I wish there was a way to implement the solution without a placeholder option.